# Solving the equation $(3x + \sin x) \cos x = -3$

Tags: trigonometry

I got stuck on solving the following equation. I try all the identities, but hopeless. Do you have any suggestion?

> $$(3x + \sin x) \cos x = -3, \quad\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi$$
>   Solve for $x$.

Please don't tell me to use the calculator!

Comment: Solutions do not appear to have a closed-form. If the only thing we can know about the zeros are approximations, then what do you want us to tell you?

Comment: Why not use the calculator? There is almost certainly no "closed form" solution.  So if one wants some kind of answer, one will have to use a numeical method of some kind. There is a unique solution in your interval, not far from $x=2$.

Comment: By chance, is the equation supposed to be $(3x+\sin x)\cos x=-3\pi$? Did you encounter this problem in a trig course, a calculus course, or somewhere different?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a closed form for this. You can only revert to numerical solutions, which are gotten from graphing the equation. One way to simplify the original is:

$$3x \cos x + \sin x \cos x = -3$$

Multiplying both sides by 2 leaves us with:
$$6x \cos x + 2\sin x \cos x = -6$$

Then you could note $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$ to get to:
$$6x \cos x + \sin 2x = -6$$

From here, I would just plug in a few points and graph it to find a solution if I was told not to use a calculator.